# How to display only tag <h1> in string, reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, string, tags

how to display only tag  in variable string,

```
const textHtml = "<h1>What events are you looking for today?</h1> <p>Find more events you want!</p>"
```

**output : What events are you looking for today? Find more events you want!**

**expected : What events are you looking for today?** just show the tag h1, the tag p, i won't the tag p is showing

and the output only display tag `<h1>` and the tag `<p>` is delete/not showing, cause value string of `textHtml` is a value from api response. And i don't how to display only the tag `<h1>`.

can anyone help me, please? And sorry for my bad english, thankyou

Comment: If I am not correct, you want to remove the content of `<p>` element from `textHtml` ?

Comment: yes, i want to delete `<p>`,

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you want to remove the whole `<p>` element from the `textHtml` string. You can easily achieve it by using `RegEx` with the help of [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const textHtml = "<h1>What events are you looking for today?</h1> <p>Find more events you want!</p>"

const res = textHtml.replace(/<p>*.*<\/p>/, '');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: and can i ask you something, if you want to delete the tag h1 too, just display only the text `What events are you looking for today?` is it possible?

Comment: @Bayu To achieve that you can use `String.match()` method which will return an array and then you can get the first index element from that. Here you go : `res.match(/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/)[1]`

Comment: ahh, i see, so let's say if i want to remove or change or anything(tag) in textHtml, i must use regex to apply it?

Comment: @Bayu Yes you can do that via regex along with JavaScript String functions.

Comment: @Bayu Please do accept this answer if it helps. So that it will be helpful for other fellow developers as well facing same kind of issue.

Comment: ahh ya, thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

`&lt;h1&gt;What events are you looking for today?&lt;/h1&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

You're storing multiple HTML elements in a string, but you'll likely want to wrap multiple elements in a `<Fragment>`, i.e.:

```js
import { Fragment } from 'react'

const titleAndP = (
   <Fragment>
      <h1>What events are you looking for today?</h1>
      <p>Find more events you want!</p>
    </Fragment>
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the code. You can do it with empty tags (typical in ReactJS)

```
const html = (
    <>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>paragraph</p>
    </>
)
```

Comment: i guess, i can't do that, because the value of content textHtml from api response

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this under your code

```
<Markup content={textHtml} />
```

source: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/display+string+with+html+tags+react+js

Comment: sorry if my words are confusing, I mean, I want to remove the p tag, i just want to display the h1 tag only

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).